# Extract values from rows satisfying a given criteria

Tags: matlab, find, accumarray

I would like to calculate total income in a shop every 30 minutes,

I have a dataset like:

```
hour  minute   price

0      1        12,5
0      1        10
0      2        15
0      3        15
```

I have tried to implement the totalling like this:

```
[rows,cols,vals] = find(0 < data(:,2) &  data(:,2) < 31 );
```

but cannot get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use logical indexing to obtain the prices in a 30 minute range:

```
data(0 < data(:,2) &  data(:,2) < 31, 3)
```

**Why find doesn't do what you expect?**

`find` works on the result of the following expression `0 < data(:,2) &  data(:,2) < 31`, i.e. `[1    1    1    1].'` It doesn't know anything about the original matrix `data`. Therefore, the second and third argument are useless in this case. They would be useful to obtain the [nonzero elements in a matrix](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html#budqvni-1).

As a (less efficient) alternative to logical indexing, you can obtain the same result as follows:

```
data(find(0 < data(:,2) &  data(:,2) < 31 ), 3)
```

**Selecting a specific hour**

At the moment, you select the prices for the first half of each hour. To select for example the prices between 00:00 and 00:30, you could use the following:

```
data(data(:,1) == 0 && 0 < data(:,2) &  data(:,2) < 31, 3)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but I doesnt work since it returns values at 2nd hour, 3rd, 4th hour...so on. I would like to  add values between 00:00 - 00:30, 00:30-1:00, 1:00 - 1:30 ....

Comment: Of course you should add an additional condition on the first column.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
data(:,2) =((data(:,2) ./ 30) + 1);
data(:,2)= floor(data(:,2));
changes = find(diff(data(:,2)))+1;

for i=1:1:(length(changes) -1)
A(i)=sum(data(changes(i):changes(i+1),3))
end
```